# How to change frequency of old monitor Compaq P75 in 12.04

Tags: radeon, monitor, frequency

Unable to modify frequency of Tube Monitor Compaq P75, Monitor should work at 85 Hz (1024*768) bud does only 60 Hz. Graphic: RADEON 7500 ATI RV200.

Answer (score 0):

first check available option for your monitor by using this:

```
$ xrandr
```

you should get such result:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1280x800       60.0*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9
```

which shows available resolutions and refresh rate
now you can choose one of them. like:

```
$ xrandr -s 800x600 -r 60.3
```